# "1064 You have an error in your SQL" while try to execute INSERT using Symfony2 and Doctrine2

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I'm executing a query using Symfony2 and Doctrine2 ORM but I get this error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO
>   stock_detail_has_product_detail (content, created, modified,
>   deletedAt, stock_detail, upc, product, condition, company,
>   product_detail) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params
>   ["Negro", "2013-09-29 02:54:46", "2013-09-29 02:54:46", null, 1,
>   "AR024MHLXF83XZO3LQ78", 1, 1, 51, 1]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition,
>   company, product_detail) VALUES ('Negro', '2013-09-29 02:54:46', '201'
>   at line 1

And I can't find what is causing this, I check tables, columns length all and seems to be ok, can any give me some tips or point me in the right direction?

PS: The query is generated internally by Doctrine since I'm only persisting objects to DB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"condition" is a reserved word in mysql (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). This has to be escaped - or renamed. I'm not familiar w/ Doctrine, so I cannot say, if there is a possibility to escape the field. But perhaps you can change the model's field name?

Regards,

Comment: got same issue with the word "**order**" (in the list of sql reserved word). Such a shame that SQL exception are not more obvious